# fetching information from google place api to display in android app

Tags: android, json, google-api, google-places

I want to make an application in android which searches for restaurants based on the details like food,expense,rating etc...i think i can use Google place API for doing it, 
I have searched for it and has come to know that in JSON interface we can add only reference and sensor as queries.So if anybody has done this before please lend me a helping hand.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8428209/show-current-location-and-nearby-places-and-route-between-two-places-using-googl/8428414#8428414

Comment: i don't want any map-view i just want to fetch location or information from Google places API

Comment: @agen451, Hear you can get the list of the  restaurants based on the details like food,expense,rating etc by using Please API,
 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8383863/how-can-find-nearest-place-from-current-location-from-given-data/10412165#10412165

Comment: Step by step implementation of the plase API http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8383863/how-can-find-nearest-place-from-current-location-from-given-data/10412165#10412165